# Update two rows in MS Access by SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can i update two rows with one query in ms access...

I tested manny codes but noone worked for me...

```
UPDATE tblSecondProductItems 
SET secondProductItemLot = CASE
when secondProductItemCode = '616161911659' then 20
when secondProductItemCode = '611611965166' then 21
end
where secondProductItemCode in('616161911659','611611965166')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem this statement is causing? Does it error out? produce the wrong result?

Comment: It commes error: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE
when secondProductItemCode = '616161911659' then 20
when secondProductItemCode = '611611965166' then 21
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `CASE`.  You can use `SWITCH()`:

```
UPDATE tblSecondProductItems 
    SET secondProductItemLot = SWITCH(secondProductItemCode = '616161911659', 20,
                                      secondProductItemCode = '611611965166', 21
                                     )
    WHERE secondProductItemCode IN ('616161911659','611611965166')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
UPDATE tblSecondProductItems 
CASE
    when secondProductItemCode == '616161911659' then secondProductItemCode = 20
    when secondProductItemCode == '611611965166' then secondProductItemCode = 21
END
WHERE secondProductItemCode in('616161911659','611611965166')
```